# How to create a navigation that open from bottom of screen?

Tags: java, android

I want to create some thing like drawer menu that open from bottom of screen.
some thing like blow image. Also I want to know is that any special name?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BottomSheet library. It works on Android 2.1+

https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet

Answer (score 1):

It's called a `SlidingDrawer`. It was on the SDK but got deprecated a while back.

That said, [this thrid-party library](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) should do the job just as good. I've used it in multiple projects.